# how scrapy and pyspider send requests to web server

Tags: python, scrapy, pyspider

I am learning the creeper frame: scrapy and pyspider, and I am curious about how do they send requests to web server.

Does they use the python module: [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/master/), or buit-in module urllib?

Any advice is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Scrapy uses [Twisted Agent](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py)

Comment: @paultrmbrth So is module Twisted associated with other requests module? Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, Twisted uses raw sockets to communicate with peers. It implements its own HTTP stack

Comment: @paultrmbrth It is really nice  of you. Thank you.

Comment: pyspider uses tornado.httpclient